# how to filter object in realm?

Tags: react-native, realm, expo

I am working on a react native project and I am using realm to store data in local database to my object is like bellow

```
[
{
title: 'title1',
data: [{name: 'name1', city: 'paris'},{name: 'name2', city: madrid}]
},
{
title: 'title2',
data: [{name: 'name4', city: 'londer'},{name: 'name6', city: roma}]
}
]
```

my question is how can i filter by data properties so for example select only the object that in their data there is an element city === 'londer'

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Realm.open({schema:[*Your_Schema*]}).then(realm => const data = realm.objects('*Your_Type*').filtered('*Your_Condition*'));
```

Check this [link](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#queries) for more details.